# Check for alphanumeric inputs and spacing

Tags: java, android

I am currently checking for alphanumeric inputs using a method which works fine. But how can I check for spacing too? As in I want to return true if the input has numbers, alphabets and/or spacing.

```
public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String input){
    if(input.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+")){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String target){
    String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$";
    return target !=null && target.matches(pattern);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.